# Change the color of an image with imagemagick

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, imagemagick, image-manipulation, rmagick

I want to change the foreground colors of an image using rmagick/imagemagick. To be more specific: I want to convert the [black](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/img/glyphicons-halflings.png) or the [white](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png) [glyphicons-halflings](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/img/glyphicons-halflings.png) icons(which are included in twitter bootstrap) into darkblue glyphicons-halflings icons. (It would be nice if I could specifie a hexcolor or RGB color.)

I have no idea if this is even possible but I clicked through the imagemagick documentation and the only thing I found is `convert --size 100x100 xc:skyblue glyphicons-halflings.png -composite foo.png`, the problem is that this only works when you specifie a size and that it is changing the foreground color not the background color. Besides it is skyblue not darkblue.

So anyone who has an idea how I could convert the white or the black glyphicons-halflings into blue glyphicons-halflings icons? (Bonuspoints for rmagick/ruby code snippets)

Comment: Don't promise bonuspoints if you can't deliver them...  :-)

Comment: The only bonuspoints you *can* deliver on SE are called 'bounty' :-)

Comment: Hi @micheal-perr, please see my answer. Does it solve your problem? Please, just let me know. Att

Answer (score 38):

**Quick answer**:

```
convert glyphicons-halflings.png -alpha extract -background blue \
-alpha shape blue-glyphicons-halflings.png
```

[image: blue-glyphicons-halflings.png]

Note: instead of `blue`, you can use any named colors, or RGB, or RGBA, etc (see http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#fill).

**Explanation**:

We "colorize" the icons in a two-step process:

- Extract the alpha channel from the icons; (note: the color of the original icons doesn't matter, we're extracting its alpha channel)
- Apply the above mask over a colored background of your choice;

For more information, read the following docs:

- http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#alpha_extract
- http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#shapes

PS: The above solution has been researched while implementing jQuery ThemeRoller rewrite https://github.com/jquery/download.jqueryui.com/issues/77

Answer (score 5):

From http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#replace, you can replace all colors in the image that are not `darkblue` with `darkblue` with the following command:

`convert glyphicons-halflings.png -fill darkblue +opaque darkblue glyphicons-halflings.png`

If you want to do it in ruby, I'd recommend using the Minimagick gem https://github.com/minimagic/minimagick which simply calls `convert` on the command line. From my experience, not all functionality has been ported from the command line to RMagick

Answer (score 3):

In addition to sguha's answer - here's the Ruby version (albeit for QuickMagick):

```
require 'quick_magick'
source = "images/source.png"
dest = "images/saved.png"
foreground = "0000ff" #hex code for your colour

QuickMagick.exec3("convert #{source} -fill \"##{foreground}\" +opaque \"##{foreground}\" #{dest}")
```